# TypeScript 1.3 protected error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

Recently installed new TS version into VS2013 and tried to use `protected` modifier.
However TS validator shows me an error (and underlines `protected` word with a red line.
I get an error like

> Use of future reserver word.
>   ; expected

looks like it's looking into old TS definitions.
Checked the project file and there is *1.1* version of TypeScript.
also running `tsc -v` produces `1.3.0`.

Does somebody of you guys experience that?
What i'm missing and what to do to fix that.

Thank you a lot for any help.[image]

```
export class SomeClass {
    protected metadata: Metadata;
    protected subItems: SomeClass[];
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your code as the image is a little over-cropped for me to honestly recreate what you may have?

Comment: @Steve Fenton
added a code above.
the issue is that parser does not recognize 'protected' identifier, and also all new features in TS 1.3

Comment: That code snippet will do - I can now see the context you have added `protected` to. (i.e. I would expect an error if you didn't have that within a class, which your image doesn't show).

Comment: Just to help others find this, the error message is `Use of future reserved word`. There was a slight typo in your post and I couldn't get any hits from search engines. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

thank you all guys. for your answers!
the reason was (oh, what's the shame =) ) the **ReSharper**.
It's validation was showing that error, suspending it i'm getting no errors now.
Looks like JetBrains guys should update their definitions like Web Essentials did.
As they aren't compatible with new TS version, 1.3. And no updates pending as for now.

Hope, it'll be useful for somebody else.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question then is [ReSharper 9.0 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+9.0+EAP).
It supports TypeScript 1.3 features: 'protected' modifier and tuples.
You're welcome to try it. Though, yes, it's a pre-release version, so overall stability is not strictly guaranteed.

Comment: Mine was a Resharper error as well.  Turning off Resharper for Typescript removed the squiggly.

Comment: Sorry, we had a bug in language detection. TypeScript 1.3 package has compiler/language version 1.3, but visual studio tools version 1.1, and that's why ReSharper was mistaken about it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-427823. Now you'll be able to specify TS version manually if auto-detect fails. Fix will be present in the coming EAP 8.

Answer (score 2):

Are you building from within Visual Studio, or from the command-line?  What with different versions of the SDK being installed, as well as potentially the NPM package globally (if you've ever installed that), it can get quite messy as to which version gets picked up.  For example, if I run 'where tsc' from the command prompt, I get the below hits (and this is without the 1.1 SDK on the path, though I am in the bin folder for testing the latest bits)

```
S:\src\TypeScript\bin>where tsc
S:\src\TypeScript\bin\tsc
S:\src\TypeScript\bin\tsc.js
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.js
C:\Users\billti\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc
C:\Users\billti\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd
```

Can you verify via "where tsc" the locations and order you PATH is resolving the 'tsc' command?

That said, if you're building from within a VS project, it should locate the latest SDK via the build target.  Does this also occur with a new TypeScript project (where the latest version and targets file should be referenced)?

Failing that, and I hate to say it... ready... did you try rebooting? :-)  Sometimes updates to the PATH etc.. after an install don't get picked up until processes restart, and things like MSBuild can actually linger waiting for the next build as a perf optimization, rather than exit once the build is done (and thus may not pick up environment changes immediately).

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work for me too. What I did to fix it was installing VS2013 Update 4 and after that, I executed the TypeScript 1.3 setup again and did a repair.

Also, you should make sure you **don't** have `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.0</TypeScriptToolsVersion>` in your csproject defined. Set it to `1.1` (not 1.3) or remove it entirely (then it will use the latest one). Hope that helps!

Comment: Dick van den Brink, thanks, for your answer. but re-install didn't help me, version is correct although

Comment: You say the version is correct, are we talking about the tsc.exe and VS2013 Update 4? Also, I noticed that I had an error in markdown with the <> signs, causing the TypeScriptToolsVersion verison stuff to not being visible. Did you checked that?

Answer (score 1):

You can determine whether the issue is related to Visual Studio pointing at the wrong TypeScript version by following these steps.

Place this example code in `C:\Temp\app.ts`

```
interface Metadata {
    something: string;
}

export class SomeClass {
    protected metadata: Metadata;
    protected subItems: SomeClass[];
    constructor() {
    }
}

export class OtherClass extends SomeClass {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.metadata = null;
    }
}

var x = new SomeClass();

// Not allowed
// x.metadata = null;
```

Run the command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.1>tsc --module amd c:\Temp\app.ts
```

Taking care to ensure you are pointing at the `1.1` folder in the TypeScript SDK folder.

The output should be:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.1>
```

i.e. nothing, except you now have an app.js file.

You can also re-run the test after uncommenting the `x.metadata = null;` line - at which point you should get the error:

> c:/Temp/app.ts(22,1): error TS2445: Property 'metadata' is protected and only accessible within class 'SomeClass' and its subclasses.

Next Steps...

**If the above fails**, please supply details of the problem.

The only real answer we could give though it remove it and check the 1.1 folder is gone before re-installing it by fetching the installer fresh from the Microsoft website (perhaps you have a bad installer or there was some problem during installation?) You may also want to check that you are on Visual Studio Update 4, as I am testing it on Update 4.

**If the above worked as expected**, your Visual Studio is not pointing at the correct version.

This could be because of the project file as Dick van den Brink has correctly mentioned. Check that you have `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.1</TypeScriptToolsVersion>` and that it is the only element with this name.

It can also be down to any Visual Studio extensions that may be messing with your TypeScript (for example, if you had a really old version of Web Essentials - in which case, update it - if it is some other extension, try disabling it).